# How to turn a Rails JSON object into readable JSON using Objective -c

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using [NSRails](https://github.com/dingbat/nsrails) in Objective -c:

```
NSError *error;
    posts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[Post remoteAll:&error]];
    NSLog(@"%@", posts);
```

I'm getting this back:

```
2013-10-07 22:03:11.377 MyBlog[19411:303] [NSRails][OUT] ===> GET to http://localhost:3000/posts 
2013-10-07 22:03:11.813 MyBlogr[19411:303] (
    "<Post: 0x101a0eb80>"
)
```

How would I take something like this `"<Post: 0x101a0eb80>"` and turn it into normal JSON?

It's weird because when I go to `http://localhost:3000/posts.json` (or without the ext. ".json"), I get this:

```
{
id: 1,
created_at: "2013-10-06T22:18:24.219Z",
updated_at: "2013-10-06T22:18:24.219Z",
galleries: [
{
id: 1,
name: "my gallery",
user_id: 1,
post_id: 1,
created_at: "2013-10-06T22:20:54.446Z",
updated_at: "2013-10-06T22:20:54.446Z"
},
```

Comment: can you give a simple project with your trouble?

Comment: Hey @Bimawa. I'm just recreating this app -> https://github.com/dingbat/nsrails/tree/master/demos following along with the video tutorial listed under it but instead of an iOS app, I'm trying to make it into an mac os x app

Comment: i can't help, sry its need more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling NSLog like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", posts);
```

Is not going to serialize your object into JSON. It's simply going to try and display a description of the object. In this case, a [description](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description) of an NSArray.

It is not clear to me why you're trying to get the JSON back. Are you simply trying to verify that your object is properly instantiated and contains the data you expect?

Set a breakpoint on your NSLog statement. Once the debugger stops, try:

```
po [posts objectAtIndex:0].name
```

This should confirm that the name property is "my gallery". However, if you really want to get JSON back from your object you'll want to look at [NSJson](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).